# PHP show data based on Yesterday and Today

Tags: php

I have an question about show data table based on date. In this case I want to show data based on today and yesterday.

Design table :
**form_no | model_name | prod_status | date_added**

Example data :
1 | acer | OK | 12-APR-2013
2 | acer | NG | 11-APR-2013

So if in table I just want the data will show once, because the model name is same.
Table view Like this

**No | Model | Yesterday Status | Today Status**
1 | acer | NG | OK

and here is my code :

```
$today = date("j-F-Y");
$yesterday = date("j-F-Y, time() - 60 * 60 * 24;");

$query = "SELECT model_name, prod_status, date_added FROM t_production_status WHERE date_added like '$today%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Now I'm done show data by today in table, now I want to display yesterday status to table view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE date BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Comment: I'd prefer this approach, but the field must be datetime for this to work. The sample given doesn't look like datetime.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider you can do it by `WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND NOW()";`

Comment: that still requires the date to be in a format MySQL can recognize.

Comment: Maybe this would work: `WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_added,'%d-%b-%Y') BETWEEN ...` ... can't test it right now though.

Answer (score 4):

Use `BETWEEN` in your query

```
$start_date = /* Yesterdays date */ ;
$end_date = /* Yesterdays date */ ;

$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date_field BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date";
```